# How to start when building a custom map?

Tags: java, android, maps, latitude-longitude

I want to build an empty map that I can customize as I like. Now, I know how the whole system works with the tiles and lon/lat coords, but I still dont understand how to contect between my tile's pixels and the lon/lat. I want to have an empty map that shows only my country and that I can edit things the way I like (I work with Android - dont know if it matters).

Answer (score 0):

Write a class which derives from the [Overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html) class and override the [onTap()](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html#onTap%28com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView%29) method. Then you can add your overlay to the your [MapView](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html). A [GeoPoint](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) object, which represents the position of you tap, is passed to the onTap() method when you tab somewhere on the map.

You also can use onTouchEvent(). Given the screen coordinates of the touch, you can use a Projection (from getProjection() on MapView) to convert that to latitude and longitude.

Here is a [sample project](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android).